# ActionListener for multiple buttons-Swing

Tags: java, swing, static, compiler-errors, actionlistener

```
public class string implements ActionListener{

    JLabel jlab;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Ae){
         jlab.setText(Ae.getActionCommand());
     }

        public static void main(String args[]){
            JFrame j = new JFrame("HP");
            j.setSize(300,300);
            j.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            j.setDefaultCloseOperation(j.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            j.setVisible(true);    

        jlab=new JLabel("Here");
        j.add(jlab);

            JButton j1=new JButton("Button1");
            j1.setActionCommand("Your pressed Button 1");

            j1.addActionListener(this );

            j.add(j1);

            JButton j2=new JButton("Button2");
            j2.setActionCommand("Your pressed Button 1");
            j2.addActionListener(this );
            j.add(j2);
    }
   }
```

I want to handle the actions of multiple buttons using the same EventHandler. When the buttons are clicked, the text of the label would be changed accordingly.

This code is showing the error that

```
Non static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context.
```

How can I rectify this code?

Comment: Most of the stuff in the main method should be moved to a constructor or a non static `init()` method.  That would solved the immediate problem - since `this` will exist.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bjava%5d%20Non%20static%20variable%20this%20cannot%20be%20referenced%20from%20a%20static%20context.%20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to your problem:

1. Use a constructor

   ```
       public class buttons1 implements ActionListener{

           JLabel jlab;

           buttons1(){


                   JFrame j = new JFrame("HP");
                   j.setSize(300,300);
                   j.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                   j.setDefaultCloseOperation(j.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                   j.setVisible(true);    

                   jlab=new JLabel("Here");
                   j.add(jlab);

                   JButton j1=new JButton("Button1");
                   j1.setActionCommand("Your pressed Button 1");

                   j1.addActionListener(this );

                   j.add(j1);

                   JButton j2=new JButton("Button2");
                   j2.setActionCommand("Your pressed Button 2");
                   j2.addActionListener(this );
                   j.add(j2);


           }

           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Ae){

                     jlab.setText(Ae.getActionCommand());

           }



           public static void main(String args[]){
               new buttons1();
           } }
   ```
2. Or, Create an object of the same class within the main and pass it to the `addActionListener` method. Also make the JLabel static.

   ```
   public class buttons2 implements ActionListener{
       static JLabel jlab;

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Ae){

                                jlab.setText(Ae.getActionCommand());

                            }



       public static void main(String args[]){

           buttons2 s = new  buttons2();

           JFrame j = new JFrame("HP");
               j.setSize(300,300);
               j.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
               j.setDefaultCloseOperation(j.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
               j.setVisible(true);    

               jlab=new JLabel("Here");
               j.add(jlab);

               JButton j1=new JButton("Button1");
               j1.setActionCommand("Your pressed Button 1");

               j1.addActionListener(s);

               j.add(j1);

               JButton j2=new JButton("Button2");
               j2.setActionCommand("Your pressed Button 2");
               j2.addActionListener(s);
               j.add(j2);
          }
      }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand what a [static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) variable is and how it works. Static variables can not be referenced from a non-static context.

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class Stackoverflow implements ActionListener{

    private JLabel jlab; /* It's a good practice to make your variables private or protected */



    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Stackoverflow();
    }
    public Stackoverflow(){
            JFrame j = new JFrame("HP");
            j.setSize(300,300);
            j.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            j.setDefaultCloseOperation(j.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            j.setVisible(true);    

            jlab=new JLabel("Here");
            j.add(jlab);

            JButton j1=new JButton("Button1");
            j1.setActionCommand("Your pressed Button 1");

            j1.addActionListener(this );

            j.add(j1);

            JButton j2=new JButton("Button2");
            j2.setActionCommand("Your pressed Button 2");
            j2.addActionListener(this );
            j.add(j2);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Ae){
         jlab.setText(Ae.getActionCommand());
    }
}
```